# Import ng2-uploader in angularcli

Tags: typescript, angular, angular-cli

Trying to import [ng2-uploader](https://github.com/jkuri/ng2-uploader) in a fresh angular2 cli project.

---

## Installing :

```
npm install ng2-uploader
```

---

## Implementation1 from node_modules:

If i try importing it directly from node_modules like this:

```
import {UPLOAD_DIRECTIVES} from 'ng2-uploader/ng2-uploader';
directives: [UPLOAD_DIRECTIVES],
```

> I get 404 no found error: http://localhost:4200/ng2-uploader/ng2-uploader 404 (Not Found)

---

## Implementation2 from system.config.ts

In **angular-cli.build.js** i guess it's the easiest step to do:

```
var Angular2App = require('angular-cli/lib/broccoli/angular2-app');

module.exports = function(defaults) {
  return new Angular2App(defaults, {
    vendorNpmFiles: [
       ...
      'ng2-uploader/*.js',   
    ]
  });
};
```

In **system.config.ts** i tried this:

```
const map: any = {
    'ng2uploader': 'vendor/ng2-uploader'
};

/** User packages configuration. */
const packages: any = {
  ng2uploader: {
    defaultExtension: 'js',
    main: 'ng2-uploader.js'
  },
};
```

Next i do `ng build`, i see the files copied in vendor folder and i try import from Vendor files:

```
import {UPLOAD_DIRECTIVES} from 'ng2uploader';
or 
import {UPLOAD_DIRECTIVES} from 'ng2-uploader/ng2-uploader';
```

> And i get compilation error.

I suspect **i'm doing something wrong in system.config.ts**. Can someone tell me what it is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried it and this worked for me.

```
import {UPLOAD_DIRECTIVES} from 'ng2-uploader/ng2-uploader';
```

Make sure you are doing :

```
ng2-uploader: {
  defaultExtension: 'js',
  main: 'ng2-uploader.js'
}
```

Comment: I just tested on 2 angularcli projects on 2 separate pc's and same 404 not found. Did u add  directives: [UPLOAD_DIRECTIVES]  and are u using algularcli?

Comment: yes,I am using angular-cli. but I followed different approach.I have edited your question for my changes

Comment: It works! Thank you! This was my mistake in`angular-cli.build.js` : `'ng2-uploader/**/*.js' `. CORRECT IS: `'ng2-uploader/*.js' `

Comment: @Cris glad to hear that